# UIColectionView with different UIViews inside

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm fairly new to developing apps using swift and I'm trying to create a `UICollectionView` with different `UIViews` inside so I can render different charts to hopefully achieve something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGaRE.png).

However I have created my `UICollectionView` and have got it to display using Storyboards and code. The following code displays data without trying to render the charts:

```
import UIKit

class MoodChartsViewController: UIViewController, 
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let locationNames = ["Monthly Mood Overview", "Mood Count", "Average Daily Mood", "Activity Count", "Often Together"]

let locationDescription = ["A count of all the moods in the month of ", "A count of all the moods tracked for the month of ", "Your average daily mood.", "An activity count for the month of ", "Moods which are often together. use this as insight to improve your mood"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.ChartName.text = locationNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.ChartDescription.text = locationDescription[indexPath.row]

    //This creates the shadows and modifies the cards a little bit
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

    return cell
}
}
```

My storyboard looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aHD5.png)

An example of the code I thought I could use to render `UIViews` inside the charts was as follows:

```
let chartViews = [UIView(ChartView), UIView(ChartView), UIView(ChartView), UIView(ChartView), UIView(ChartView)]
```

With the `UIView` class which renders a `XIB` file (just to get something on the screen):

```
import UIKit

class ChartView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    UINib(nibName: "monthlyviewcount", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(view)
    view.frame = self.bounds
}
}
```

But this error message appears:

> Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

I think I might be overthinking this a little but is their an easier way to achieve this? or am I just missing something simple?

Comment: If you are using storyboards then you don't need to use NIB files; Simply  create your cell prototypes in the storyboard and give each one a different reuse identifier.  Which line do you get the error on?  You are not doing anything with the result of calling `instantiate`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your help. The error happens when I try use the array of UIViews (let chartViews = ...). I got that code online somewhere just to try it out. So if I create different UIViews with reuse identifiers, do you think it will be possible to use the code: let chartViews = [UIView(ChartView), ...] to add the views in?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the array of chart views.  I would create appropriate `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses, each that had the appropriate chart view in it.  `UIView(ChartView)` doesn't mean anything.  What is `ChartView`?  There is no form of the initialiser for `UIView` that takes an anonymous argument, which is why you get the error.

Comment: @Paulw11 The "ChartView" was just the name of the UIView class I created. My thinking was, for example, if you had a UIImage view instead of the UIView, creating an array of images by using: `let chartView = [UIImage("test")]` would allow you to fill each UIImageView with the images, I just thought the same could be applied when using a UIView. I'll give your suggestion a go, thanks or your help.